# Force a single viewcontroller in the story board in landscape

Tags: objective-c, ios7, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation, orientation-changes

My Project have 2 views 1. Mainview controller 2. Settingview Controller .
I want my main view controller to support all orientations but the setting view controller should be in landscape mode irrespective of the device orientation. Right now I am facing issues like 
1. Even if the scene is in landscape mode the view appears as portrait
2. `(BOOL)shouldAutorotate , (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` not getting fired.

Any help is appreciated.[image: My story board is as shown in picture.]

Comment: Did you also implement preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation? This gets called BEFORE your VC is presented and gives you a chance to tell the system which way you prefer it be shown (if you don't implement this, it will default display to the orientation of the status bar).

Comment: It is already implemented.